# Navigate between multiple storyboards in iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone

I wanted to have separate storyboard files for every UIViewcontrollers in my iOS app.

So how can we assign different storyboards for each controllers? Also how do we do navigation between those?

This I am doing to avoid svn conflicts while so many people working on UI.

Comment: Here's a link that might help http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/02/18/ios-storyboards-xcode5/

Answer (score 0):

get a reference to the storyboard...

```
UIStoryboard *someStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NameOfYourStoryboard" bundle:nil];
```

then instantiate either the initial viewcontroller from that storyboard...

```
UIViewController *initialViewController = [someStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

or some other viewcontroller identified by it's storyboard identifier...

```
UIViewController *someOtherViewControllerFromTheStoryboard = [someStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SomeViewControllersStoryboardIdentifier"];
```

after that you can simply push (within a navigation controller) or present the new viewcontroller.

since iOS 9.0 you can even connect storyboards via storyboard references in the storyboard itself:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/AddSBReference.html

Answer (score -1):

Keeping different storyboards for different modules is good approach. You can achieve the navigation between storyboards as follows:-

Suppose you are in A view controller and want to push another view controller named `FabIdeaDetailViewController` which is present in storyboard named `FabIdeas`:-

```
FabIdeaDetailViewController *horizontalListController = (FabIdeaDetailViewController*)[UIViewController instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FabIdeaDetailViewController" fromStoryboard:@"FabIdeas"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:horizontalListController animated:YES];
```

Now for pushing another view controller named `WishlistViewController` which is present in storyboard named `Wishlist`:-

```
UIViewController *WishlistViewController = [UIViewController instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WishlistViewController" fromStoryboard:@"Wishlist"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:WishlistViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: the method `[UIViewController instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FabIdeaDetailViewController" fromStoryboard:@"FabIdeas"]` is not existant.